# Guvnor execution server getting 401 when using AD-configured Guvnor as endpoint

Tags: drools

We are using:

• Drools Execution Server that came with Drools 5.0.x
• Drools Guvnor 5.2 configured with active directory

The execution server and guvnor run on the same Tomcat and use the same port.

With the execution server you can have a listener for each package within the configuration file. I have two such files, from-file-system.properties that points to a local directory where a drools binary package is manually deployed. This works fine.

But I try to use with-guvnor.properties which points to a package binary on 5.3 Guvnor. Here is the file:

```
name=ndipiazza
newInstance=true
# Absolute path of the directory containing pc.drl: placeholder replaced by Ant.
url=http://localhost:9109/drools-guvnor/rest/packages/NDD_Test/binary
poll=10
```

I get the following error:

```
RuleAgent(ndipiazza) INFO (Mon Jun 18 18:11:32 EDT 2012): Configuring package provider : URLScanner monitoring URLs:  http://localhost:9109/drools-guvnor/rest/packages/NDD_Test/binary
RuleAgent(ndipiazza) WARNING (Mon Jun 18 18:11:34 EDT 2012): Was an error contacting http://localhost:9109/drools-guvnor/rest/packages/NDD_Test/binary. Reponse header: {null=[HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
```

Some sort of authorization error very likely related to the active directory configuration within Guvnor 5.2.
This used to work for us just fine with an earlier version of Guvnor.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we isolated the problem today. Drools Server 5.0.x cannot support a URL endpoint when it has authentication of any sort.

I reported a bug: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3554

Without these changes, this will not work.

drools-core's `org/drools/agent/HttpClientImpl.java`

These two methods need to have authentication added in (marked by START and END NDD), and obviously switched with your username/password.

```
public LastUpdatedPing checkLastUpdated(URL url) throws IOException {
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) con;
        try {
// **** START NDD ***** 
            BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
            String userpassword = "ad-user" + ":" + "ad-password";
            String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode( userpassword.getBytes() );
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+
                  encodedAuthorization);
            // **** END NDD *****             



            httpCon.setRequestMethod( "HEAD" );            


            String lm = httpCon.getHeaderField( "lastModified" );
            LastUpdatedPing ping = new LastUpdatedPing();

            ping.responseMessage = httpCon.getHeaderFields().toString();

            if ( lm != null ) {
                ping.lastUpdated = Long.parseLong( lm );
            } else {
                long httpLM = httpCon.getLastModified();
                if ( httpLM > 0 ) {
                    ping.lastUpdated = httpLM;
                }
            }

            return ping;
        } finally {
            httpCon.disconnect();
        }

    }

    public Package fetchPackage(URL url) throws IOException,
                                        ClassNotFoundException {
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) con;
        try {

            // **** START NDD ***** 
            BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
            String userpassword = "ad-user" + ":" + "ad-password";
            String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode( userpassword.getBytes() );
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+
                  encodedAuthorization);
            // **** END NDD *****             




            httpCon.setRequestMethod( "GET" );

            Object o = DroolsStreamUtils.streamIn( httpCon.getInputStream() );

            if ( o instanceof KnowledgePackageImp ) {
                return ((KnowledgePackageImp) o).pkg;
            } else {
                return (Package) o;
            }
        } finally {
            httpCon.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Mystery solved.